# Firebase Audience is not showing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have created Custom Audience in firebase and generated plenty of users and events but after two days audience data is empty against every custom audience, except All users.

[image: Here is Audience Image]

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to the audiences not being built?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: After adding audience in firebase, log ample of  events that satisfies audience criteria. Log events from atleast more than 10 devices, so that audience tab will show some result And follow the Official Firebase tip mentioned by @Sneh Pandya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the same country set in your project settings as you are living? 
Data update times vary largely based upon region or country selected among all Google Services. Generally they follow PST (Pacific Standard Time).

Wait for 12 hours, if it still doesn't get updated, contact Firebase Support Team.

[Official Firebase tip](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en) says: Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified criteria from that point onward by virtue of the events that their devices log. When defining new audiences, **it may take some time for the lists to populate. Before targeting an audience in Notifications or Remote Config, be sure to check the number of users for your audience to see if it looks reasonably well developed.**

Comment: Yes. I have set same country in which I am living.